# Whether TFS 2010 work with Visual Studio 2010 Solution which targets .NET 3.5 Framework?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, tfs

I have an application built with Visual Studio 2008. I have converted this to Visual Studio 2010. I do not want to change the framework version. So it's targeted to .NET version 3.5. Now I put this project on TFS 2010. But there is no option of "Add Solution to Source Control". I have already set up TFS 2010 server. I just need to add this application on TFS. Whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

.net version is not relevant here, TFS should work.

It seems you have a problem adding your solution to TFS source control, load your solution to VS & go to "File">"Source Control" ~> isn't there an option "Add to source control"?

Comment: I have not found Source Control at File > Source Control, but found at Team Explorer. Which tells me to select the Plug-in Selection from Tools > Options. At here I just select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" from drop down then everything seems to work fine. Thanks for your great hint.

Comment: Glad to be helpful! You might also want to consider placing @flysakura answer as your accepted solution instead of mine.